# MATLAB's Textscan Format Complexity vs post-processing

Tags: matlab, text-processing, textscan

I have a question about MATLAB's `textscan`. I have a file with a **very large number of columns**, and anywhere from 1-32 rows (very small when compared to #col). Here is a simple example:

```
Test1 1 2 3 4 5
Test2 6 7 8 9 10
```

**The number of columns aren't known ahead of time**, the length of the first and only string that begins a line isn't known ahead of time. I read in the first line and count the number of columns, and build the actual format string to read in the rest of the file as can be seen below:

```
function output = parseFile(filename) 

%% Calculate Number of Samples
% Reads in first line
tic
fid = fopen(filename);
line = fgetl(fid);
fclose(fid);
firstLine = textscan(line, '%s', 'CollectOutput', true);
numSamples = size(firstLine{1},1) - 1;
toc

%% Parse File
tic
fid = fopen(filename);
format = ['%s ' repmat('%f', [1 numSamples]) '%*[^\n\r]'];
fileData = textscan(fid, format, 'CollectOutput', true);
fclose(fid);
 toc

%% Format Output
output.names = cell2mat(fileData{1});
output.values = fileData{2};


end     % end function
```

I've picked a couple examples, and each time I get the following: Say I have a file with 100,000 columns and 3 lines. The `tic`/`toc`s tell me that the first line read finishes in .16 seconds. When I then build the format string and read the entire document, it finishes in 9 seconds. Why does the first line when read in as a `%s` read in so quickly, but the next time I read the entire file (of only +2 more lines) it takes dramatically longer? Is it because of the more complicated `format` string with which I'm parsing the file the second time around? Would it just make sense to parse the entire file as a space separated string and then perform post-processing (ex:`str2double`) to get my matrix of doubles?

EDIT: Clarification on specifics of file format:

```
(string of unknown length)(1 space)(-123.001)(1 space)(41.341)(1 space)...
...
```

So numbers are *not* `int`, and they're positive/negative.

NOTE: What Im essentially confused about, is why textscan was able to read the first line of the file very quickly, while the next two lines took **much** longer than the first.

Comment: Maybe. I've found textscan to be slow sometimes too. str2double takes time too though. You can run the profiler (not tic/toc) and see what is taking so long inside textscan. It may very well be the str2double function called within textscan.

Comment: Tuning string parsing in MATLAB can be a sport. If your input is as in your example, my bet is that the fastes way is to chop off the initial string, and then use sscanf(s, '%i') on the rest of the line. Parsing ints is much faster than parsing floats.

Comment: Some questions: The range of numbers include negative values? Do you always have one space between numbers?

Comment: clarified above with the format of the file, and followup question

Answer (score 1):

A usual trick to convert a string into a number is to delete `double('0')` from the string. Besides, this way is much faster than `str2double`. For example, running this code:

```
% Using -double('0')
tic, for i=1:1e5;  aux='9'-48;      end, toc
% Using str2double()
tic, for i=1:1e5;  str2double('9'); end, toc
% Using str2num()
tic, for i=1:1e5;  str2num('9');    end, toc
```

I get:

```
Elapsed time is 0.000480 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.445741 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.524999 seconds.
```

Hence, you can construct a function that parses each line (this function could be more optimize, I guess):

```
function num = parseText(str)
    strCell = strsplit(str,' ');
    strNum = cellfun(@(s) s-48, strCell(2:end),'UniformOutput', false);
    nNum = numel(strNum);  num = zeros(1,nNum);
    for idxNum=1:nNum, 
        num(idxNum) = strNum{idxNum}*10.^(length(strNum{idxNum})-1:-1:0).'; 
    end
end
```

If you try for one line, the result is fine:

```
str = 'Test1 0 1 2 3 4 5 10';
num = parseText(str);
```

If you try for several lines, it also seems fine:

```
% Create text
L = 10;   str = cell(L,1);
for idx1=1:L, 
    strAux = []; for idx2=1:randi(10),  strAux = [strAux,' ',num2str(randi(10))];  end
    str{idx1} = ['Test',num2str(idx1),strAux];
end

% Parse text
num = cell(L,1);
for idx=1:L, 
    num{idx} = parseText(str{idx});
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! That would work great if I had `int`s! but I in general the file is composed of numbers that look like this: `-321.304 123.032`